# returning arrays and objects created in functions in various languages

Tags: java, python, c++, c, arrays

I am getting little bit confused with returning arrays and objects created locally in the function call. So I believe -

1. C - No Objects, only arrays and structures can be created on stack, so will be deleted when function returns. So its not wise to send them as return value to the calling module.
2. C++ - Objects *& structures* resides in heap, so objects can be returned but nothing else, i.e. arrays will still be destroyed when returning
3. Java - I can return arrays as well as Objects, I guess arrays moved to heap here?
4. Python - Same as Java, Objects and Arrays created locally can be returned to calling module as reference.

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Now why would java/python put arrays in heap? being interpreted languages is that the reason? So would every compiled language will not let me return locally created arrays back to calling module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Java `int[] array = new int[3]` corresponds to a C++ `int* array = new int[3]()`. A C++ (or C) `int array[3]` has no Java equivalent.

Comment: It's not a question of compiled vs. interpreted languages. Some languages have garbage collection, because it's convenient and reduces the scope for error; others don't, because simpler object management schemes can be more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. C has objects, such as instances of structs. You can return these safely from a function, provided they don't have data members that refer to variables local to the function. You can't return arrays because these are not copyable. But you can safely return structs with array data members, in which case the arrays get copied.
2. The same as C. Objects are instances of structs or built-ins. `structs` are the same as `classes`. Whether they are on "the heap" depends on how you instantiate them (this is exactly the same in C.) The only difference is that C++ has [*return value optimization* (RVO)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which allows for copies to be elided in many situations.
3. I'm not sure of the exact semantics of returning arrays, but Java has referential semantics so generally the lifetime of objects outlives their scope.
4. Similarly to Java. Lifetime is not bound to scope, so it is perfectly fine to return any type of object from a function.

Answer (score 1):

to extend a little the answer:

Python manage lifetime by reference counting. When an object has no references it'll be destructed or finalized and released. 
In Java I think that happens exactly the same

Comment: I don't think it is as deterministic as that. Typically, when the reference cound goes to zero, the objects *can* be released, but are not necessarily released. The details of when and how that happens depend on the garbage collection algorithm and implementation.